# Splitting Vector into blocks - Strange results

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix

I've been given a MATLAB function that takes in a 1D vector and two sizes, the function then splits the data into blocks and finally stores them inside a 2D vector. I have been writing a C++ version of this function, but the (incorrect) results of my C++ function do not match the (correct) results of the MATLAB function.

Matlab function:

```
function f = block(v, N, M)

% This function separates the vector
% into blocks.  Each block has size N.
% and consecutive blocks differ in
% their starting positions by M
%
% Typically
%   N = 30 msec (600 samples)
%   M = 10 msec (200 samples)

  n = length(v);
  maxblockstart = n - N + 1;
  lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1 , M);

  % Remove the semicolon to see the number of blocks
  % numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1
  numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;

  %f = zeros(numblocks,N);

  for i = 1:numblocks
  for j = 1:N
   f(i,j) = ((i-1)*M+j);
  end 
 end
```

For the purpose of this example, I'm just outputting the results of ((i-1)*M+j) and in MatLab I get these results (example):

1 201 401 601 .. 1001 1201 .. 1401 .. 1601 .. 1801

And here is my C++ function:

```c++
vector<iniMatrix> Audio::subBlocks(vector<float>& theData, int N, int M)
{
    // This method splits the vector into blocks
    // Each block has size N.
    // and consecutive blocks differ 
    
    int n = theData.size();
    int maxblockstart = n - N+1;
    int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - mod(maxblockstart-1, M);
    
    int numblocks = (lastblockstart-1)/M + 1;
    
    vector<float> subBlock;
    vector<iniMatrix> block;
    
    for(int i=1; (i < numblocks); i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; (j < N); j++)
        {
            cout << ((i-1)*M+j);
        }
        
    }

    return block;
}
```

The result I get from this:

1 2 3 4 .. 7 8 9 .. 13 14 15 etc..

P.S.

iniMatrix is just a typdef for the a vector of floats..

Another note, the variables:

> n
>
> maxblockstart
>
> lastblockstart
>
> numblocks

All have the same value in the Matlab program and the C++ so I think it's something to do with the for loops..

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just a thought: in MATLAB the first element in a vector has the index '1', but in C++ the first element in say an array has index '0'. So perhaps you could try starting the for-loops at zero.

Comment: @S.C.Madsen Hey I've tried that, no luck! It's weird, everything has the same value, apart from what I actually need lol the i*M+j :(!

Comment: "*I've **literally** tried everything.*" - I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: I am not sure if this solves your problem, but I thought I should mention that MATLAB contains a built-in function which has, I think, the functionality you desire. The built-in function is called `buffer`.

Comment: @cjh: The problem is the C++ code, not the MATLAB code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if I've understood your desired algorithm correctly.
Say
n = 10
N = 3
M = 2

This should yield 
0, 2, 4, 6 right? (since 8 won't fit because 8+M is outside the range 0 <= x < n).

So, maxblockstart should be 7 = 10 - 3, that is n - N

lastblockstart should be 6 = 7 - 7 % 2, that is maxblockstart - maxblockstart % M

and numblocks should be 4 = 6/2 + 1, that is lastblockstart/M + 1

Modifying your code as follows, seems to yield the right results (only worked this out on paper, haven't tried compiling or executing.....):

```
vector<iniMatrix> Audio::subBlocks(vector<float>& theData, int N, int M)
{
  int n = theData.size();
  int maxblockstart = n - N;
  int lastblockstart = maxblockstart - (maxblockstart % M);

  int numblocks = (lastblockstart)/M + 1;

  vector<iniMatrix> block;    

  for(int i=0; (i < numblocks); i++)
  {
     vector<float> subBlock;
      for(int j=0; (j < N); j++)
      {
          subBlock.push_back(theData[i*M+j]); //cout << (i*M+j);
      }  
      block.push_back(subBlock);
  }

  return block;
}
```

Give it a try...

Note that comparing results against MATLAB can be confusing, since C++ indicing is zero-based. Thus try the following;

1) Change the line `cout << (i*M+j);` to `cout << theData[i*M+j];`

2) Try the following test:

```
vector<float> test;
for(int i=0; i<=10000; i++)
  test.push_back(i);

Audio::subBlocks(test, 1023, 200);
```

Comment: Note, the results are "zero-based" which you should keep in mind when comparing results against your MATLAB results. You could fill the input vector with values 1..n and print the contents, i think that would yield directly comparable results.

Comment: It should increment by 200.. So for example, it should go: 1, 201, 401, 601, 801, 1001, 1201, 1401, 1601 .. .. .. 57201 and then J would go onto 2.. 2 202 402 602 etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I tried your code and I get.. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.. and why should C++ go 0, 200, 400?

Comment: Or, if you would like directly comparable results, try filling the 'theData' vector with values 1,2,3,... And then change the "cout << (i*M+j)" with "cout << theData[i*M+j]"

Comment: I tried theData and got complete different results to what I get in MatLab hence I printed out the [i*M+j] this is weird! Could it have something to do with the way I print it out.. For example, in Matlab I print it as f(i, j) ...

Comment: Please observe that I want you to replace theData contents with the integer-series: 1,2,3,.... for testing purposes. I'm assuming this is for some kind of signal processing on overlapping audio buffers, then the first 200 "samples" in C++ would mean the range of indices 0,1,2...,199

Comment: Thanks! When I print out theData[i*M+j] I get the same results as I would normally?? It hasn't split the data up at all.. What am I doing wrong exactly aha? E.g. why does matlab range from 1, 201 etc.. and C++ is supposed to start from 0, 1, 2.., 199? Thanks for your help, would really like to solve this!

Comment: As mentioned, the first element in a MATLAB vector is accessed like x(1), where the first element in a C++ vector is accessed like x[0]. If my solution worked, please mark as "solution" by clicking the tick-mark and perhaps vote up the answer if you want.

Comment: Hey, but it doesn't work, since it's printing the wrong results than what I get in MatLab. I need to store the value of (201) in the 1st element inside the vector, instead it's storing the 1st element in the 1st element of the new vector..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16848/discussion-between-s-c-madsen-and-phorce)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but where do you write the values of the 1D vector in the output ?

maybe you need to change this :

```
  for i = 1:numblocks
  for j = 1:N
   f(i,j) = v((i-1)*M+j);
  end 
 end
```